# R Markdown not knitting to Word using R Studio

Tags: html, ms-word, r-markdown

I am new to `R Markdown`. I have a file that knits well into `HTML` format. However, when I try to knit into `Word`, it does not work.

I get the following error and warning message(s):

```
output file: preliminary_analysis3.knit.md

Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting docx output.

Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of your rmarkdown file:

  always_allow_html: true

Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML formats.

In addition: Warning message:

In in_dir(input_dir(), evaluate(code, envir = env, new_device = FALSE,  :
  You changed the working directory to C:/Users/username/Desktop (probably via setwd()). It will be restored to C:/Users/username/Desktop/R_Test/RMarkdown Testing. See the Note section in ?knitr::knit
Execution halted
```

I have tried to play with the `YAML` header in following ways:

##### Sol 1:

```
title: "My Project 1"
output: word_document
```

##### Sol 2:

```
title: "My Project 1"
output: 
  word_document:
    toc: yes
    always_allow_html: true
```

I have also tried to change the code itself:

##### Sol 3:

I previously had `HTML` tables using the `DT` function. I have changed them into `knitr::kabble(my_table)` in the hopes that they may resolve the issue.

None of these is working, I would greatly appreciate any advice that can help me understand the warning or error messages or how to address them. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score -1):

I was having a similar problem with the Rmd file not knitting as it should. The error was caused by a faulty package install.

uninstall / reinstall markdown package and restart, then for me, the default knit output was a .doc which was changed in the output settings.

Maybe this will help you, if not the issue regarding Markdown/ Pagedown is open on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you @Zane, Which package should I install?

Comment: "Please reinstall rmarkdown correctly.

You can install the last version of xfun and use xfun::broken_packages(reinstall = TRUE) to check for corrupted packages and reinstall them. This could be long as it will test all the installed package. You could just try library(rmarkdown) and follow the error to reinstall the packages with issue.

If library(rmarkdown) is working well, this is something else with the library going on. But as stated above, this is an issue with the IDE and an issue is opened there."  [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1990)